# Dynamical functions on comprehensive lists (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, dynamic

I will demonstrate my question with a simple example: (non-optimal) prime number distinguisher.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
    | n < 2     = False
    | otherwise = ( and [ n `mod` d /= 0 | d <- [2 .. (n-1)] ] )
```

Notice that `and` outputs `True` if and only if every value in the comprehensive list is `True`.

Suppose now I throw in a query `> isPrime someVeryLargePrime`. Then the function `and` will receive a huge list, each of whose entries being `True`.

#### Question

I understand since Haskell is lazy the function `and` might be smart enough to output false once it detects any `False` in the list.

1. However, while the list contains lots of `True`, is it smart enough to compress the list **while it is reading the list**? For example, while the first two entries are True, then release the memory by contracting both `True` values to one `True` value, and so on.
2. If not, how does one write a function that deals with a comprehensive list **dynamically**?

Comment: THe list is (to the best of my knowledge) never constructed. This is a good example of how *list fusion* could boost efficiency.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Indeed it is never constructed. From haskell report `7.14.4` which defines list fusion,  list comprehension are a _good producer_ and `and` function is a _good consumer_. :)

Comment: List fusion is an advanced optimization which avoid allocating the list entirely. You do not have to understand when that triggers to reason about the code you wrote. What you need to understand is that `and` will only demand a list until the first `False`, and no more. Further, the list cells created in such way can be garbage collected after they have been inspected. Hence, even without list fusion, a good GC system should run your code in O(1) memory.

Comment: I don't fully understand you guys (pretty new to computer), but it sounds remarkable! I will get back to this issue later as it seems very advance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the effective answers in comments:

- The comprehension never produces the entire list, it likely produces the head of the list and a thunk to produce the next element when it would be accessed.
- The `and` function never consumes the whole list, it only consumes the head element and calls itself recursively for the tail.

This way, there's no need to ever produce more than the head of the list for the whole computation.

This is how you can work with *infinite* lists: `take 5 [0 ..]` never produces the entire list for obvious reasons.

Regarding the performance of `and`.

In GHC standard library, [it is defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#and) either via `foldr` or via `x && all xs`.

The latter is not tail-recursive. The former uses [`foldr` implementation from List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr) which is also not tail-recursive.

This puzzles me: either would produce a stack as large as the input, if interpreted naively; I would expect an accumulator parameter implementation, strict (`!`) by the accumulator.

Maybe GHC knows how to effectively compile such non entirely tail-recursive constructs to effective loops, *I don't know.*

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough. I understand that the whole list is not constructed, but as `and` reads in a sequence of `True`, does it create a stack? I should have asked this question in a simpler way: how many layers of stack does `and` creates when `and [True, True, True, True, True]` is executed? Is it 2? or 5?

Comment: If I'd write a naive version of `and` (again, I don't really know how powerful `and` is written), and let's call it `naiveAnd`, then it would look something like `... naiveAnd (x:xs) = x && naiveAnd xs`. This is not good, since it is going to call 5 layers in my example above. Whereas a better way is so that as the function reads in the first `True`, it knows immediately that it can **safely forget this information** and keep proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for your update! I hope someone knows the answer to that.

Comment: Tail recursion isn't always necessary for good performance in a lazy language. Indeed the most common trick you use to rewrite code to be tail recursive (introducing extra accumulator parameters) is frequently *harmful* to performance in Haskell.

Comment: Haskell is *lazy*. tail recursion will always consume the whole input list, will never cut the evaluation short (unless with exceptions or non-local exit etc). when the combining function is short-circuiting, i.e. lazy in its second argument, the non-tail, aka *"guarded"* recursion is the way to go, in foldr as well. `&&` is one such combining function. `+` isn't.